# Why is y needed in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

I saw this sentence in an article online about a video game:

> Bref, tout y passe dans les améliorations à venir.

My understanding still is that *y* is used to replace a noun when the verb is followed by *à*, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, or if it is the case I can't see how. It seems like you could just remove the *y* and the sentence would still be right.

Comment: Yes, originally *y* stood for [par quelque chose], [dans quelque chose]: *~ Tout passe par l'énumeration de l'éditeur de jeux vidéos des améliorations a venir* = *On voit tout passer dans cette énumération*; *Tout y passe*. But that [quelque chose] becomes undefined, secondary, inferred from the context in the set expression *tout y passe* (see jiliagre's answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[**Tout y passe**](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/75266)* is an idiom roughly meaning 'Everything go through it' but better translated to 'nothing is left/forgotten' (in the upcoming enhancements). In your case, all that was mentioned before will be taken into account.

Dropping the ***y*** wouldn't work well here, ***Tout passe*** has different meanings.

Here is a good translation from WordReference.com when *tout y passe* is detached from the rest of the sentence, an idiom too: *[**You name it**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tout-y-passe.304711/#post-1833020)*.

The French text is actually a translation from this one by Xavier Campbell ([samagame.com](https://samagame.com/en/latest/forget-starfield-the-most-ambitious-sci-fi-video-game-of-all-time-just-delivered-a-monumental-blow/?expand_article=1)):

> Regarding destructibility, CIG confirms that it is working on how the nature of an object and its characteristics cause different reactions, with the idea of ​​making them all more organic in this way. In general, the game’s physics are expected to improve noticeably in the coming months (water, light, weather conditions such as clouds and fog), and CIG will rely on suites of technologies (HDR, Ray Tracing, DLSS/FSR upscaling) to enhance everything. **In short, improvements are being made in all aspects, both when it comes to graphics and sound.**

Here is the full translation of that paragraph ([jeuxvideo.com](https://www.jeuxvideo.com/news/1814756/oubliez-starfield-le-jeu-video-de-science-fiction-le-plus-ambitieux-de-tous-les-temps-vient-de-nous-mettre-une-claque-monumentale.htm)):

> Pour ce qui est de la destructibilité, CIG confirme travailler sur la manière dont la nature d’un objet et ses caractéristiques entraînent des réactions différentes, l’idée étant de les rendre toutes plus organiques de cette façon. De manière générale, c’est la physique du jeu qui est censée nettement progresser d’ici les mois à venir (l’eau, la lumière, les conditions climatiques (nuages, brouillard)), et CIG va s’appuyer sur des ensembles de technologies (HDR, Ray Tracing, upsaling DLSS/FSR) pour sublimer le tout. **Bref, tout y passe dans les améliorations à venir, autant d’un point de vue graphique que sonore.**

I agree that the idiom ***tout y passe*** immediately followed by ***dans*** or ***pour*** is at first sight ambiguous. We need to read the whole sentence a couple of times before grasping its content. It is nevertheless not that rare, other occurences can be easily found, e.g.:

---

[image]
[Amazon](https://www.amazon.fr/Petit-dictionnaire-%C3%A9nerv%C3%A9-Laurence-Desbordes/dp/2360750348)

---

> Des pieds aux oreilles jusqu'à la queue en tire-bouchon, **tout y passe dans le cochon**.

[Worldpress - Cochon de lait](https://whileitcooked.wordpress.com/tag/cochon-de-lait/)

---

[image]

Rolling Stone, Déc. 2020 -Jan. 2021

---

> Elle trouve premièrement en son chemin cette basse région ; elle y voit des fleuves qui coulent, des fleurs qui se flétrissent du matin au soir ; **tout y passe dans** une grande inconstance.

Bossuet, Panégyrique de Saint Benoît, 1665.

---

> Stupre, crasse, paresse, suicides, parasitisme... **tout y passe dans** l’image que donne de lui la grande presse.

Jeannette Colombel, *Jean-Paul Sartre : un homme en situations*, 2000.

---

> [...] barque en radoub, flombart dieppois, trois mâts à Tancre, cotre échoué sur la vase, bateau pilote avec pavillon en berne, galiote hollandaise en déchargement, chaland remorqué, canot lamaneur en pleine mer, embarcation de plaisance glissant sur la Seine, steam-boat au repos dans un bassin à flot, pyroscophe qui fume avant son départ, chasse-marée en réparation sur la grève, péniches dans leur chantier à Compiègne, chaloupe de pèche que la marée a déposée sur la plage. — **Tout y passe dans** ces trente-sept tableaux, formant un vrai musée naval, comme dans « Navarin » des Orientales de Victor Hugo.

Paul Eudel, *L'hôtel Drouot en 1881*, 1882

---

> Avec ce compagnon des truands, échappés de la Cour des Miracles de Notre-Dame de Paris et naturalisés espagnols, Hugo s'en donne à cœur joie, à cœur rimes. Mots rares, vocables juteux, vers flambants, airs de bravoure, **tout y passe dans** une gaillardise hâbleuse, depuis « sa cape en dents de scie et ses bas en spirales » jusqu'à « une duègne, affreuse compagnonne »,
>      Dont la barbe fleurit et dont le nez trognonne...

Paul Guth, *Histoire de la littérature française*, 1981.

---

> — Ah! madame, vous ne le connaissez pas!... C’est un ours, un nouveau paysan du Danube. Il ne va nulle part, il est toujours débraillé comme un matelot, il boit, il joue, et il brise... cristaux, assiettes, glaces, porcelaines, **tout y passe dans** leurs soupers.

Eugène Labiche, *L'homme de paille*, 1843

Comment: Hmmm. Moi au contraire, j'enlèverai le _y_ dans la phrase de l'OP? J'ai l'impression d'une redondance ou d'un style relâché. Il faudrait avoir un peu plus de contexte.

Comment: @Frank La phrase n'aurait plus de sens, ou du moins pas le même sens. Le style est un peu relâché, c'est vrai, mais la formule est très courante en France.

Comment: Here is the extra context, but I believe @jlliagre is correct here. « De manière générale, c’est la physique du jeu qui est censée nettement progresser d’ici les mois à venir (l’eau, la lumière, les conditions climatiques (nuages, brouillard)), et CIG va s’appuyer sur des ensembles de technologies (HDR, Ray Tracing, upsaling DLSS/FSR) pour sublimer le tout. Bref, tout y passe dans les améliorations à venir, autant d’un point de vue graphique que sonore. »

Comment: Idioms still get me. I'm getting way better at recognizing them, but sometimes it still gets past me because it looks like an ordinary construction and I'm sitting there trying to make it fit not realizing it's a set phrase.

Comment: @temporary_user_name I don't know if it's an idiom, or if it is, it's a modern one/a relaxed way of speaking, not necessarily an entirely correct idiom to reproduce. I think it could be frowned upon. Personally, I wouldn't write that, I would find it defective/grating to the ear. I would write "tout passe *par* les améliorations à venir" or something like "on va fourrer tout ça dans des améliorations à venir".

Comment: @Frank *Tout passe par les améliorations à venir* means something different. *On va fourrer tout ça* has a different register and tone. *Tout y passe* was already used in the 19th century so isn't particularily modern, it is neither relaxed or incorrect. It can be found for example in two Académie Française speeches like that one: [Tout y passe, en effet, la flore, les animaux et les parties du monde ; les humbles travaux des jours et les sept sciences ouvrant à l’activité humaine les sept voies ; les saints...](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/reponse-au-discours-de-reception-de-emile-male)

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, mais la construction que tu donnes en example n'est pas tout à fait la même que celle de l'OP. Il y a plusieurs substantifs qui viennent préciser _tout_, alors que _y_ se rapporte à quelque chose dans le contexte. Dans _tout y passe dans les améliorations à venir_, à quoi se rapporte le _y_? Je donne deux possibilités légèrement différentes, car je trouve _tout y passe dans_ ambigu, en fait. C'est la combinaison de _y_ et de _dans_ qui me gêne dans ce cas précis. Sans doute parce que _passer dans_ a aussi un sens.

Comment: @jlliagre Si on veut se rapprocher de la construction que tu donnes, il faut mettre une virgule: _tout y passe, dans les améliorations..._, et là, oui, c'est bien la même construction, aucun problème. Sans cette virgule, ça ne _passe_ pas pour moi. Dans la construction que tu donnes, il y a même deux virgules et un _en effet_ pour isoler "_tout y passe_" de l'énumération qui suit, mais ce n'est pas du tout le cas pour l'OP, et en plus, _passer dans_ est legit, ce qui rend le tout un peu ambigu à mes yeux.

Comment: @jlliagre Euh... Moi je traduirais _In short, improvements are being made in all aspects, both when it comes to graphics and sound._ par _Bref, les améliorations vont viser tous les aspects, à la fois graphiques et son._ Je ne vois pas trop la nécessité de _tout y passe (dans)_ ici.

Comment: @Frank Le fait d'avoir utilisé *tout y passe* est plutôt à l'honneur du traducteur qui ne s'est clairement pas appuyé, au moins pour cette expression, sur un outil de traduction automatique. C'est la *French touch* :-)

Comment: @jlliagre Quand je serai à l'Académie, je ferai en sorte que cette expression soit marquée d'une _F_ ;-)

Comment: Je rejoins @frank il y a ambiguïté dans la construction : on pourrait comprendre "Bref, tout passe dans la catégorie améliorations à venir" (Tout change de catégorie), et le y devient redondant. En revanche la construction "Bref, dans les améliorations à venir, tout y passe" enlève complètement cette ambiguïté de mon point de vue. Par contre je n'ai pas de problème avec l'idiome en soit, tant qu'il est bien isolé dans la phrase.

Comment: @jlliagre D'un point de vue statistique, deux exemples à mon avis ne permettent pas de conclure "not that rare" - le lecteur pourrait avoir l'impression que c'est une forme courante, alors que par exemple, les ngrams donnent _tout y passe dans_ pour _très rare_ parmi les usages de _tout y passe_.

Comment: @Frank Je me doute que je ne te convaincrais pas mais j'ai quand même ajouté d'autres exemples.

Comment: @jlliagre De très beaux exemples! Bon travail :-)

Comment: @jlliagre Notes bien que les _dans_ dans tes exemples n'ont pas tous la même valeur, et l'effet d'ambiguïté est inégal. Dans le cas de Bossuet et Guth, je trouve que ce qui suit le _dans_ peut assez facilement être détaché du _y_, alors que dans les autres cas, j'ai beaucoup plus l'impression d'une redondance entre le _y_ et le _dans_.